# getAccountInfo Google Call Slow and Load-Blocking in Ionic Firebase App

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, ionic3, google-cloud-firestore

The title pretty much says it all. I have an Ionic/AngularFire/Firestore app and there is a call Google makes to:

https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/getAccountInfo

An example app that has the problem is:

https://musicblobs.com

In the waterfall, the getAccountInfo always takes about 800ms and blocks everything else from downloading. Does anyone know any way around this?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I'm seeing this with firebase + ionic5 & 6 (I don't think ionic has anything to do with it, but I'm guessing the firebase SDK version might?)

Comment: Hey @santeko -- nope I didn't but you can load stuff before Firebase auth loads and populate the DOM/whatnot so it looks like its quick